# How do i create new files wen given a new id?

Tags: lua

im creating a discord bot but i would like the logs to be put in files named [channel id].txt

currently i have my bot logging to log.txt
its confusing to have everything log to 1 file but whenever i try to use os.execute to copy then rename a file or to create a new file nothing works

```
local parsemsg = function(message)
if (sharebot.log_messages) then
print('LOG: ', message.timestamp, message.channel.id, message.author.tag, message.author.id, message.id, message.content)
file = io.open('./log.txt', 'a+')
file:write('LOG: ', message.timestamp, ' ', '<#', message.channel.id, '>', ' ', message.author.tag, ":", '<@!', message.author.id, '>', ' ', message.id, ': ', '\n', 'MESSAGE: ', message.content, '\n\n')
file:colse()
end
```

sorry if the code is a little hard to read, i have a issue where i forget to add spacing

i would like to have a file [message.channel.id].txt created whenever a new channel id is fed into it but whenever i try something like

```
if not (file) then
os.execute("echo LOG START > ", message.channel.id, ".txt")
file = io.open(message.channel.id, '.txt', 'a+')
end
```

or

```
if not (file) then
os.execute("copy l.txt > ", message.channel.id, ".txt")
file = io.open(message.channel.id, '.txt', 'a+')
end
```

it does not create a new file

Comment: One problem in the bottom two blocks is that `io.open` takes two arguments – file path and mode – but you've given it three arguments. Replace `io.open(message.channel.id, '.txt', 'a+')` with `io.open(message.channel.id .. '.txt', 'a+')`.

Comment: Similarly, `os.execute` takes one argument. Concatenate the arguments you've given to it (replace `, ` between the arguments with ` .. ` ).